# How to apply a variable in Azure Pipelines to a node app during build

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have created a [Framework7.io](http://framework7.io) website that uses the Svelte plugin.

It's using webpack.

I can pass in an environment variable, as part of the npm script - for example:

[image]

The variable is then picked up in the webpack.config.js file:

[image]

This works locally, just fine.

When using Azure Pipelines, how can I apply a variable in place of hardcoding?

I tried switching out my actual URL with a variable, setup in Azure Pipelines. I.E `$(MY-BASE-URL)` - though it's not actually being replaced.

[image]

How do we apply pipeline variables to the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do we apply pipeline variables to the build?

You could try to use the **Replace Tokens task** from the [Replace Tokens Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

Here are the steps:

1. Set the `#{varname}#` (e.g. `#{MY-BASE-URL}#` ) in the package.json file
2. Set Pipeline variables and use the Replace Token task.

[image]

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

You could use the `$variablename`(e.g. `$MYBASEURL`) in package.json.

Then it will directly get the value from pipeline variable.

**Note:** Based on my test, the `-` character will truncate variable names. I suggest you could change to use `_` (e.g. `$MY_BASE_URL`)

[image]

Comment: oh, sweet. nice extension, I'll give it a whirl, thank you. do you know how people are doing this without the extension?

Comment: Hi @DarrenWainwright. Of course.  Please refer to my update. You could use $variablename in package.json. I have shared some of my test result in the update too. In this case, you don't need to add  additional tasks. This will be easier.  Hope it helps.