# Dependency inject MSAL Javascript library

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am working with a development team that is leveraging Microsoft's MSAL.js library for a vanilla javascript application.  The authConfig.js has the following necessary code:

```
const msalConfig = {
auth: {
  clientId: "11111111-1111-1111-111111111111",
  authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111111111111",
  redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/",
},
cache: {
  cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
  storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
}
```

I need to be able to change the clientId and RedirectURI for Dev, QA and Prod.  Is there a way to dependency inject these values for the DevOps pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to dependency inject these values for the DevOps pipeline?

I would like to share the following two methods:

Method1:

You can add PowerShell task in each stage to replace the value of `ClientId` and `redirectUri`.

1.Set the variable to save the Old value and New Value.
[image]

2.Run the following Powershell script:

```
(Get-Content  .\authConfig.js).replace('$(oldid)', '$(newid)') | Set-Content  .\authConfig.js

(Get-Content  .\authConfig.js).replace('$(oldredirectUri)', '$(newredirectUri)') | Set-Content  .\authConfig.js
```

Method2 :

You could try to use the Replace Tokens task from the [Replace Tokens Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

For more info, you can refer to this ticket: [Replace token task ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66540307/13464420)

Comment: Thanks Kevin! That is helpful!