# Best way to change a docker image tag in a azure pipeline with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

I have my azure pipeline doing a kubernetes@1 task with my kubernetes config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tenant-service-deployment
  labels:
    app: tenant-service
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tenant-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tenant-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: tenant-service
          image: cronesharedwesteurope.azurecr.io/tenant-service:dev
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80   
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registrysecret
```

You can see that at the moment my image is hard coded in my yaml file (tenant-service:dev).

I want the user to tell me witha azure devops pipeline parameter which version he wants (e.g, dev / 1.0 / latest). But because the kubernetes is a yaml config file, I can't change it with a parameter, can I? Are there any tools to do exactly this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PassionateDeveloper for my case destination was GKE and we were using Azure DevOps for CI/CD. Requirements was to use Build.BuildID as image tag to uniquely distinguish all the image tags. Here is what I had used to fulfil the requirements.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: {name of my self hosted agent pool}
  
variables:
  imageTag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
```

My kubernetes manifest looked like this.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: authenticator
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: gcr.io/myproject2/myapp:${imageTag} ---> imageTag to be replaced with replaceToken task
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

I have used the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens to do the magic for me.

```
- task: replacetokens@5
            inputs:
              rootDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/MyProjectDirectoy/Manifests/'
              targetFiles: '**/*.*'
              encoding: 'auto'
              tokenPattern: 'custom'
              tokenPrefix: '${'
              tokenSuffix: '}'
              writeBOM: true
              verbosity: 'detailed'
              actionOnMissing: 'fail'
              keepToken: false
              actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
              enableTransforms: false
              enableRecursion: false
              useLegacyPattern: false
              enableTelemetry: true
```

So my overall my deployment stage yaml file would look like this and it is working like a charm.

```
- stage: Production
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build


  jobs:
  - deployment: Production
    displayName: Production
    environment: $(envName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: replacetokens@5
            inputs:
              rootDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/MyProjectDirectory/Manifests/'
              targetFiles: '**/*.*'
              encoding: 'auto'
              tokenPattern: 'custom'
              tokenPrefix: '${'
              tokenSuffix: '}'
              writeBOM: true
              verbosity: 'detailed'
              actionOnMissing: 'fail'
              keepToken: false
              actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
              enableTransforms: false
              enableRecursion: false
              useLegacyPattern: false
              enableTelemetry: true


          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: 'deploy'
              kubernetesServiceConnection: 'GKE'
              namespace: 'default'
              manifests: |
               $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/MyProjectDirectory/Manifests/01-Deployment.yml
              imagePullSecrets: 'azure-pipelines-deploy-token-djmc7'


          - task: PostBuildCleanup@3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what we do at work,

1. Create a build pipeline that builds the docker image with a tag, and the tag is the pipeline build number, e.g. #1.6.1-TenentServiceImage. (Assume that you have already pushed the image to ACR during the build process).
2. In your deployment YAML pipeline, add a resource,

   ```
      resources:
       pipelines:
        - pipeline: TenentServiceImage
          source: Tenent Service Image
          branch: master
   ```
3. In the same YAML, now you can reference the resource in your image path,

   ```
    image: cronesharedwesteurope.azurecr.io/tenant-service:$(resources.pipeline.TenentServiceImage.runName)
   ```
4. When your devs try to deploy the container, they click Run and should see a new selection dropdown **Resource** and select the build they want to deploy.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you, never heard about ressources in Azure DevOps, I use variables and parameters - can you maybe explain me why a ressource is available in the yaml file but the parameters isnt?

Comment: These documentations probably explain better than me, for resources, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema ;and for variables vs parameters, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/inputs?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

> I want the user to tell me with an Azure Devops pipeline parameter which version he wants (e.g, dev / 1.0 / latest).

To meet your requirements, you can use **RegEx Match & Replace task** from [RegEx Match & Replace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kasunkodagoda.regex-match-replace).

This task will use regular expressions to match fields in the file.

In this case, you can define the parameter for users to input and pass the value to the task to replace the tag.

Here is an example:

```
parameters:
  - name: dockertag
    type: string
    default: dev
    

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: RegExMatchReplace@2
  displayName: 'RegEx Match & Replace'
  inputs:
    PathToFile: test.yml
    RegEx: 'image: ([a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+)/[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+'
    ValueToReplace: 'image: cronesharedwesteurope.azurecr.io/tenant-service:${{ parameters.dockertag }}'

...
```

Then the value will update.

**Result:**

**Run Pipeline**

[image]

**Yaml file:**

[image]

You can use this site to convert the regular expressions : [Regex Generator](https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/?sampleText=2020-03-12T13%3A34%3A56.123Z%20INFO%20%20%5Borg.example.Class%5D%3A%20This%20is%20a%20%23simple%20%23logline%20containing%20a%20%27value%27.&flags=i&onlyPatterns=false&matchWholeLine=false&selection=)

Or you can also use the Replace token task. Refer to this ticket: [How to apply a variable in Azure Pipelines to a node app during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537243/how-to-apply-a-variable-in-azure-pipelines-to-a-node-app-during-build/66540307#66540307)

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft has some good [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/devops-pipeline?pivots=pipelines-yaml) on setting up an Azure DevOps pipeline for Kubernetes containers. The example features use of the [KubernetesManifest@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubernetes-manifest-v0?view=azure-pipelines) task in the pipeline allowing to specify the container tag with a pipeline variable or parameter.