# Image version by BuildID when do task 'Build module images' for iotedge - Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-iot-edge, azure-container-registry

I am building a docker image for Azure IoTEdge using pipeline, then push to Azure Container Registry. Everything worked but:

**Current the image version is fixed** (or need to set manual) in `module.json`:
[image]

However I want **image version will update by BuidID** (Or any unique ID), I tried below code but it did not work:
[image]

This is error from pipeline log:
[image]

I tried to read document [build module image](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/azure-iot-edge), but it dont have option for tagging like build image using [docker v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task.

Hope you can help me on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pipeline variable `$(Build.BuildId)` will not directly pass to module.json file.

To meet your requirement, you can add the task [File transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic) to pass the variable value to module.json file.

Here is an example:

```
variables:
  image.tag.version: $(Build.BuildId)

steps:

- task: FileTransform@1
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    fileType: 'json'
    targetFiles: 'module.json'

- task: Docker@2
```

Or you can also use the Replace token task. Refer to this ticket: [How to apply a variable in Azure Pipelines to a node app during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537243/how-to-apply-a-variable-in-azure-pipelines-to-a-node-app-during-build/66540307#66540307)

Comment: Thank you very much @Kevin, File transform task worked like a charm.