# Unable to Retrieve REACT_APP_ENV Environment Variable in React App on Azure Web App with Single Build and Multiple Releases

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, environment-variables

I'm working with a React web app hosted on an Azure Web App, and I'm facing an issue with retrieving the `REACT_APP_ENV` environment variable. My Azure pipeline involves only one build, but I have three different releases for various environments (DEV, TEST, and PROD). Naturally, I need to have different values for REACT_APP_ENV for each environment, and I want to maintain a single build for efficiency.

However, whenever I attempt to log the value of `REACT_APP_ENV` using `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_ENV)`, I consistently get an undefined result. I've tried various approaches but haven't been able to resolve this issue.

I tried to add `REACT_APP_ENV` to the application settings of the web app via the Azure Portal (in the Configuration section). Additionally, I included this variable in the pipeline's list of variables for each release.

PS: Whenever I try to log `NODE_ENV` I get "production" for all the instances.

Comment: That's baked in _at build time_, your code is running in your clients' browsers and doesn't have access to env vars in your server. Read e.g. [my blog](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to keep one build pipeline and change the **REACT_APP_ENV** value based on the different environment of Release Pipeline.

To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can use RegEx Match & Replace task from [RegEx Match & Replace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kasunkodagoda.regex-match-replace).

This task will use regular expressions to match fields in the file.

Here is an example:

js file sample:

```
REACT_APP_ENV = process.env.REACT_APP_ENV;
```

Task defintiion:

[image]

Yaml sample:

```
steps:
- task: RegExMatchReplace@2
  displayName: 'RegEx Match & Replace'
  inputs:
    PathToFile: .env
    RegEx: 'REACT_APP_ENV = ([A-Za-z]+(\.[A-Za-z]+)+)_[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+;'
    ValueToReplace: 'REACT_APP_ENV = $(REACT_APP_ENV)'
```

You can define the variable: **$(REACT_APP_ENV)** in release Pipeline variable and define the scope.

For example:

[image]

Then the value will update.

You can use this site to convert the regular expressions : [Regex Generator](https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/?sampleText=2020-03-12T13%3A34%3A56.123Z%20INFO%20%20%5Borg.example.Class%5D%3A%20This%20is%20a%20%23simple%20%23logline%20containing%20a%20%27value%27.&flags=i&onlyPatterns=false&matchWholeLine=false&selection=)

On the other hand, you can also use the task from the [Replace Tokens Extension.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

For more detailed info, you can refer to [my ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537243/how-to-apply-a-variable-in-azure-pipelines-to-a-node-app-during-build/66540307#66540307).