# Managing Environment-Specific Property Files across stages with Azure DevOps Pipeline Overrides them on stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am  facing challenges maintaining property files across our repository's various development stages.

Within our legacy monolith, all properties and config files reside inside the repository.

Our repository has three stages for `development`, `staging`, and `master` environments, obviously with varying property values across these stages.

For example, `application.properties` file contains different values for each stage:

**dev**

```
app.imagedir=E:\images
app.backupdir = E:\backup   
installdir=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\
```

**staging**

```
app.imagedir=D:\images
app.backupdir = D:\backup   
installdir=C:\IBM\WebSphere\
```

**master**

```
app.imagedir=C:\images
app.backupdir = C:\backup   
installdir=C:\IBM\WebSphere\
```

My goal is to maintain a unified `application.properties` file within the repository across all stages, yet allow these values to be overridden when the pipeline runs. How can I implement such behavior in Azure DevOps pipelines?

I'm looking for best practices, or methods to manage these environment-specific configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I implement such behavior in Azure DevOps pipelines?

I suggest that you can use the **Replace Tokens task** from the [Replace Tokens Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

Here are the steps:

1.Set the #{varname}# (e.g. #{app.imagedir}# ) in the application.properties file

For example:

```
app.imagedir=#{app.imagedir}#
app.backupdir =#{app.backupdir}# 
installdir=#{installdir}#
```

You can keep the format above in the application.properties file.

2.Set Pipeline variables in different stages and use the Replace Token task.

[image]

[image]

When you run the pipeline, the replace token task will automatically update value in application.properties file according to the variables set in the corresponding stages.

If you are using YAML Pipeline, you can define the variables at stage level.

For example:

```
stages:
- stage: dev
  variables:
    app.imagedie: E:\images
    app.backupdir: E:\backup   
    installdir: C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
    - task: replacetokens@5
      inputs:
        rootDirectory: 'folderpath'
        targetFiles: 'application.properties'
        encoding: 'auto'
        tokenPattern: 'default'
        writeBOM: true
        actionOnMissing: 'warn'
        keepToken: false
        actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
        enableTransforms: false
        enableRecursion: false
        useLegacyPattern: false
        enableTelemetry: true
```

For more information, you can refer to [my ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537243/how-to-apply-a-variable-in-azure-pipelines-to-a-node-app-during-build/66540307#66540307).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the yaml pipeline, you can use the parameters in pipelines to decide the variables value.

Sample yaml:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string
    displayName: environment value
    default: dev
    values:
      - dev
      - staging
      - master


variables:
  - name: app.imagedir
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'dev') }}:
      value: "E:\\images"
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'staging') }}:
      value: "D:\\images"
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'master') }}:
      value: "C:\\images"
  - name: app.backupdir
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'dev') }}:
      value: "E:\\backup"
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'staging') }}:
      value: "D:\\backup"
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'master') }}:
      value: "C:\\backup"
  - name: installdir
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'dev') }}:
      value: "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\WebSphere\\"
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'staging') }}:
      value: "C:\\IBM\\WebSphere\\"
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'master') }}:
      value: "C:\\IBM\\WebSphere\\"
steps:
- script: echo This is ${{ parameters.environment }} environment. app.imagedir is $(app.imagedir). app.backupdir is $(app.backupdir). installdir is $(installdir).
  displayName: 'show ${{ parameters.environment }} environment variables'
```

If you are using the classic release pipeline, you can set different variable value for different stages.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Miao!  But I have many properties and do not plan to have all in the pipeline
But the properties share two or three common paths

`app.imagedir= path1\images`
`app.backupdir =path1\backup`
`installdir= path2\install`
`otherDir=path1\other`

path1 and path2 can be different on dev, stage, and prod
but all properties have either path1 or path2

Comment: Hi @HariHaravelan, you can refer the answer by Kevin Lu-MSFT and use Replace Tokens task. It can replace all the files with the pattern you need. You can defile path1 and path2 for different stages and replace them in all files with the Replace Tokens task.